# Google Load Balancer not logging errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

We are trying to troubleshoot the load balancer of our applications and we cannot see why the load balancer is giving 502 errors. When I go to Logging and filter by severity or error code we don't see anything on the logs.

The type is External HTTPS Classic and the configuration of the load balancer is this

[image: Load balancer configuration]

I add some aclarations per [@John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) said:

I am checking the logs in google cloud logging: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query

The error is generated in the load balancer as if i check backend logs I don't see the request to have arrived to it. Also, looking at other stack overflow posts of Cloud Load Balancing it gives the same error.

Others can see the errors like the documentation says of statusDetails http failure messages: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#gcloud:-classic-mode

But we don't see any of the errors registered, nor the petition with error code 502.

Edit: To mention that we see every OK response in the logging, just the errors and warnings aren't logged.

Comment: 1) Where are you looking for the load balancer logs? 2) Are you sure that the load balancer is generating the 502 and not the backend? 3) Review the logs for the backend(s). Edit your question with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found out. Someone in the company set in the Log router sink an exclusion to http codes distinct to 200. That's why it wasn't being registered